# unable to override env PATH variable in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins Server, there are two global environment variables defined. It's in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties -> Environment variables

Name: MAVEN_HOME
Value: /var/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven3.5.2

Name: PATH+EXTRA
$PATH:/usr/local/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin

I see that PATH+EXTRA will add the MAVEN PATH to the PATH environment variable. This is how my existing Server set up is. Now I need to update Jenkins with Maven 3.8.2, so I downloaded Maven 3.8.2 in the server using Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> Maven Installations. Now I am trying to override the global MAVEN_HOME and PATH to point to MAVEN_3.8.2 path.

In the Jenkins pipeline script

```
def maven_version = 'maven_3.8.2'
pipeline {
    agent any
  stages {
    stage ('build') {
      steps {
        withEnv(["PATH+MAVEN=${tool maven_version}/bin"]) {
          echo "PATH is: $PATH"
          echo env.PATH
          echo env.MAVEN_HOME
          sh 'env'
          sh 'mvn --version'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

- echo "PATH is: $PATH" =>
  /var/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven_3.8.2/bin:/opt/java/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/var/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven_3.5.2/bin:/opt/java/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
- echo env.PATH =>   /var/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven_3.8.2/bin:/opt/java/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/var/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven_3.5.2/bin:/opt/java/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
- echo env.MAVEN_HOME =>
  /var/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven_3.5.2
- sh 'env' =>  prints all the environment variables. Noticed following:
  MAVEN_HOME=/var/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven_3.5.2
  PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven_3.5.2/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven_3.8.2/bin:/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven_3.5.2/bin:/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

**Why is the PATH is being appending with Maven 3.5.2 in the front of the path. How can I let PATH point to Maven 3.8.2?**

- sh 'mvn --version' => Apache Maven 3.5.2
  Maven home: /var/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven_3.5.2

**How do I get the mvn --version result with maven3.8.2?**

Note: I also tried with free style project, and used following commands to override the values but the mvn --version is always printing 3.5.2. Any idea if it is a bug with Jenkins unable to override the path or is there any way to do it?
export MAVEN_HOME=/var/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven_3.8.2
export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin

Answer (score 0):

The format you used to modify the `PATH` variable uses concatenation that prepends the new value to the existing one. It means that

```
PATH+MAVEN=${tool maven_version}/bin
```

is an equivalent of:

```
PATH=${tool maven_version}/bin:$PATH
```

You can solve this issue by overriding the `PATH` variable explicitly and putting the new path at the end of the variable. Try to test the pipeline like this one:

```java
def maven_version = 'maven_3.8.2'
pipeline {
    agent any
  stages {
    stage ('build') {
      steps {
        withEnv(["PATH=${tool maven_version}/bin:$PATH"]) {
          echo "PATH is: $PATH"
          echo env.PATH
          echo env.MAVEN_HOME
          sh 'env'
          sh 'mvn --version'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The output for PATH in the command sh 'env' still takes 3.5.2 in the front of the path and so mvn --verison output is 3.5.2.

Comment: This worked for me.
def maven_version = 'maven_3.8.2'
pipeline {
    agent any
  stages {
    stage ('build') {
      steps {
        withEnv(["MAVEN_HOME=${tool maven_version}"]) {
            sh '''
            export PATH=${MAVEN_HOME}/bin:$PATH
            env
            mvn --version
            '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}