# Flutter Jenkins flutter not found issue

Tags: flutter, dart, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hello all i am currently trying to build the flutter app with jenkins.
for the initial setup what i have done is there is master-slave setup in which the slave is mac machine which will create the build(slave machine is connected as well).
Below is the pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "macos16Node"
    }
     environment {
        flutter = " /Users/username/Desktop/flutter"
    }


    stages {
        stage ('Flutter Doctor') {
            steps {
                withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/opt/flutter/bin']){
                    sh '$flutter doctor -v'
                }
               
            }
           
        }
        stage('GIT PULL') {
            steps {a
                git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'github_token', url: ‘mygitrepo’
            }
        }
        stage('TEST') {
            steps {
                
                    sh ‘$flutter test'
                
                
            }
        }
        stage('BUILD') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                  #!/bin/sh
                  flutter build apk --debug
                  '''
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

when ever i build the pipeline it gives me the error

Following is the console output:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on slaveNode in /var/root/workspace/first pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Flutter Doctor)
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ /Users/user/Desktop/flutter doctor -v
/var/root/workspace/first pipeline@tmp/durable-f6dbaa4a/script.sh: 1: /Users/user/Desktop/flutter: not found
```

I have also not set any path in the env variables in jenkins.
If any one can let me know why it does not detect flutter, or do i need and additional setup for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Quick answer

**Reason:**

flutter binary is not the in the PATH of jenkins shell

**Fix:**

Download [flutter](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_3.7.3-stable.tar.xz) anywhere like **/tmp/workspace/flutter** and override the PATH in the environment.

**Jenkins 2.375.2**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
      PATH = "$PATH:/tmp/workspace/flutter/bin"
    }    
    stages {
        stage('Setup') {
            steps {
                print "${env.PATH}"
            }    
        }
        
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "flutter doctor -v"
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

**output**

[image]

## Detailed answer

There is no magic with Jenkins, **if it works in the shell, it will work with Jenkins**.

##### Steps 1: Add flutter to the shell PATH

In the machine which jenkins will execute the build commands, try the command `flutter doctor -v`. You will see this error:

[image]

Similar to the jenkins error

[image]

So, install flutter with snap

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

or download it with curl

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_3.7.3-stable.tar.xz -o /foo/bar/flutter.tar.xz
apt-get install xz-utils
tar xf /foo/bar/flutter.tar.xz
```

You should have these files `ls -la /foo/bar/flutter`

[image]

Finally you need to add the flutter to the shell PATH variable. You could use the java style

```
export FLUTTER_HOME=/foo/bar/flutter
export PATH=$PATH:$FLUTTER_HOME/bin
```

[image]

If you run the command, it will work

[image]

##### Steps 2: Add flutter to the jenkins PATH

**For declarative pipeline**, since PATH is a **special** env var, the only way to modify it is with:

```
environment {
  PATH = "$PATH:/foo/bar/flutter/bin"
}
```

Similar to the host shell example `PATH=$PATH:$FLUTTER_HOME/bin`

After that, you could use **flutter** anywhere of your pipeline

**For scripted pipeline**, these 2 options worked for me:

> #1 Modifying the PATH variable

```
node {   
  print "${env.PATH}"

  def FLUTTER_HOME = "/tmp/workspace/flutter"
  env.PATH = env.PATH+":$FLUTTER_HOME/bin"
  print "${env.PATH}"

  sh "flutter doctor -v"
}
```

> #2 withEnv PATH+EXTRA

```
node {
  def FLUTTER_HOME = "/tmp/workspace/flutter"

  withEnv(["PATH+EXTRA=$FLUTTER_HOME/bin"]){
    sh 'flutter doctor -v'
  }

  sh "flutter doctor -v"
}
```

The only problem with this latest option is that flutter will work only in the **withEnv{...}** scope.

[image]

### References

- https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-flutter-on-linux/
- https://www.cyberithub.com/how-to-install-flutter-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa/
- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-install-and-setup-flutter-on-ubuntu/
- [How to set PATH in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237051/how-to-set-path-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline)
- [unable to override env PATH variable in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852023/unable-to-override-env-path-variable-in-jenkins)
- https://gist.github.com/thinhdanggroup/90528c34e4fd4c9e1c9a945f9b88d89c
- https://dsstream.com/declarative-vs-scripted-pipeline-key-differences/

Comment: Hey @JRichardsz It seems i am new to the jenkins world, In the detailed answer step 1 i am trying to run the command on the agent machine which is a mac. and its working fine. Or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: One question in order to run on the agent node there is no need to install anything on the mater node only the path to provide?

Comment: If the jenkins job will be executed in the slave/agent, the tools should be installed there, not in the master

Comment: Hey @JRichardsz just got it resolved, my mistake was that when we set the root directory in the agent config i defaulted it to the different path that is the linux one. when i changed it to proper mac path which is Users/username/flutter. It job was success. Thanks for the information. Have a nice day